# Origin UAC every single launch

Tags: origin, windows, windows-8

***Every*** **single** *time* Origin starts I get a UAC prompt and Origin drops into the settings menu.

Sometimes even does it when unlocking PC.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour or knows how to stop it ?

Windows 8.1

Comment: Do you launch Origin manually, or does it launch at Windows boot?

Comment: It happens either way. I have it launch on boot but if I manually quit and restart same thing.

Comment: Not exactly the answer to your question, but you might find [this link](http://superuser.com/q/2699/215659) useful.

Comment: @nolonar I did see that but not sure I want UAC off totally.

Comment: Most programs that autoupdate (Steam, Origin, etc) have a background service so they can avoid the repeated UAC prompts.  Is that disabled or not started on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

One way to avoid the UAC prompt on startup, is to put a shortcut to Origin in the startup folder of your Start Menu.

There are multiple startup folders in Windows; one per user and one for the entire system. In Windows 8.1 they're located at:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp
```

and

```
C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

where `[User]` depends on the user's account name. The individual folder names may vary depending on the language Windows was installed in.

Shortcuts or apps found in these folders will automatically launch when Windows boots, which is useful for when an app does not offer a "launch on system boot" feature. If placed in the system's startup folder, the shortcut will be launched with the system's priviledges, meaning no UAC prompt.

Just keep in mind to deactivate Origin's "launch on boot" option to avoid conflicts.

This method only prevents UAC prompts when booting the PC, not when unlocking it or restarting Origin.